# Black wont fix formatting when using pre-commit.; I think?

Tags: python, formatting, githooks, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

I have been using black in the exact same set when using pre-commit, however, as soon as I incorporated pytest it always renders the below error.

```
$ git add . && git commit -m "stackoverflow added to read me for configuration"
Check Yaml...........................................(no files to check)Skipped
Fix End of Files.........................................................Passed
Trim Trailing Whitespace.................................................Passed
black....................................................................Failed
- hook id: black
- exit code: 1

Usage: python -m black [OPTIONS] SRC ...

One of 'SRC' or 'code' is required.

pytest-check.............................................................Passed
```

This is my pre-commit config file

```
repos:
-   repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks
    rev: v2.3.0
    hooks:
    -   id: check-yaml
    -   id: end-of-file-fixer
    -   id: trailing-whitespace
-   repo: https://github.com/psf/black
    rev: 21.12b0
    hooks:
    - id: black
      name: black
      entry: black
      language: system
      require_serial: true
      types: [python]
      always_run: true
-   repo: local
    hooks:
    - id: pytest-check
      name: pytest-check
      stages: [commit]
      types: [python]
      entry: pytest
      language: system
      pass_filenames: false
      always_run: true
```

Would appreciate an explanation to the answer if possible.

Answer (score 4):

you've misconfigured the `black` hook -- this is what you should use:

```yaml
-   repo: https://github.com/psf/black
    rev: 21.12b0
    hooks:
    - id: black
      # no other options here ideally -- the ones you set broke things
```

---

disclaimer: I wrote pre-commit

Comment: why did it break is that something you can answer- or it is what it is when adding pytest to the pre-config file?

Comment: that configuration as written was always broken, adding pytest was unrelated except this was likely the first time you committed with zero python file changes